# second smallest element in an array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

as a part of a C program I wrote the following function, which finds the second smallest element of an array

```c
unsigned int array_second_min (unsigned int w[], unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int i, erst = UINT_MAX, zweit = UINT_MAX, count = 0;
    
    if (n < 2)
        return UINT_MAX;
    for (i = 0;i < n; i++) {
        if (w[i] == w[i + 1])
            count++;
    }
    if (count == n - 1)
        return UINT_MAX;
    for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        if (w[i] < erst)
            erst = w[i];
    }
    for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        if (w[i] == erst)
            continue;
        if ((w[i] - erst) < zweit)
            zweit = w[i];
    }
    return zweit;
}
```

the problem is that it is not really functioning as it should. I think the problem is in the last for loop, but am not sure about that.

Thank you for your help

picture of the output:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example where it fails ? I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Off-topic: if you want someone to read your program, make sure they understand what the identifiers mean. On-topic: You do not need three loops. It is enough to look through your array exactly once. You also don't need any arithmetic. Comparing the difference of two elements with a third element is utterly meaningless.

Comment: @dspr have just attached a photo of the output

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. what will be then the logic when you do it in one run?

Comment: @Ozk basically you just scrap your first loop and merge your last two loops into one. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65549528/1025555) you got for the details.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return the second smallest element

```c
unsigned int array_second_min (unsigned int w[], unsigned int n){
    unsigned int i, first = UINT_MAX, second = UINT_MAX;
    if(n < 2)
        return UINT_MAX;
    sort(w, w+n);
    second = w[n-2];
    return second;
}
```

Comment: it seems like it can determine only the first smallest element but not the second.. Take for example the array 1 3 6 2 5

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat more efficient solution, as it is `O(n)`:

```
struct pair {
        int r[2];
};

struct pair small2(int *a, int n) {
        int r[2];
        int order;
        r[0] = a[0];
        r[1] = a[1];
        order = (r[0] >= r[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                if (a[i] <= r[order]) {
                        r[!order] = a[i];
                        order = !order;
                } else if (a[i] <= r[!order]) {
                        r[!order] = a[i];
                }
        }
        struct pair x;
        x.r[0] = r[order];
        x.r[1] = r[!order];
        return x;
}
```

There is a lack of detail about duplicates, this handles them in an unsurprising fashion.  Note the trickiness of the `order` variable; this works because you are only interested in the least two, if you wanted the least 3, you would have to add the extra tests.  It would remain `O(n)`, but the `C` would be greater.